# How to set background image opacity in CSS without pseudo before/after and/or positioned divs

Tags: html, css

I have a div generated by a CMS which includes a background image which I'd like to change the opacity of without effecting the opacity of the div's child elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/L5b81yqo/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Some dummy text</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  background: url(https://live.staticflickr.com/4561/38054606355_26429c884f_b.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Is it possible with CSS to change the opacity of the background image without using psuedo before /after (as this involves using the background URL which I can't use in the stylesheet as it's dynamic from the CMS and could be any URL) or adding additional markup (as the CMS won't let me add further markup).

I've looked at various solutions but all these appear to use the methods I can't use defined above e.g. https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-change-a-css-background-images-opacity

If it's not possible then that's fine and I can look at a workaround solution.

Comment: Its not possible to change only the background image opacity without affecting the children.

Comment: You can not apply opacity to an element, without affecting its descendants. So you will _need_ additional markup, or at least additional (pseudo-) elements for this. If you can not get the CMS to give you the image URL in some form directly, then you could read it via JavaScript on the client side, and then assign it to an additional element or pseudo element.

Comment: (Well you could do it without any additional elements, if you read the image first, put it onto a `canvas`, changed the opacity value of the pixels there, and then read the whole thing back from the canvas as a Data URI, that you could then assign instead of the original background image of the element …)

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify **why** you need to use opacity on the background. It may be that there are other options.

Comment: @CBroe we can also rely on *inherit* to get the image inside a pseudo element

Comment: Please elaborate: do you really need that background to be (partly) transparent or do you need the `background-color` of `<body>` (or `<parent>` container) peek through? Because in the last case adding the rule `.container { background-color: rgba(parent rgb values, some-opacity); background-blend-mode: screen }` may well do the trick. You will need to tinker with the value of `some-opacity` to get the desired effect. Also `lighten` may work for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> without using psuedo before /after (as this involves using the background URL which I can't use in the stylesheet as it's dynamic from the CMS and could be any URL

You can still use pseudo element and inherit the background without the need of the url:

```css
.container {
  /* I will not touch this */
  background: url(https://live.staticflickr.com/4561/38054606355_26429c884f_b.jpg); 
  /**/
  height: 400px;
  background-size: 0 0; /* make the main background hidden */
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.container::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:-1;
  background-image:inherit;
  background-size:cover;
  opacity:0.3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p>Some dummy text</p>
</div>
```

Or like below with a simple background-color layer on the top:

```css
.container {
  /* I will not touch this */
  background: url(https://live.staticflickr.com/4561/38054606355_26429c884f_b.jpg); 
  /**/
  background-size:cover;
  height: 400px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.container::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  z-index:-1;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p>Some dummy text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Cool! Actually I didn't even need the background-image, I can use your code minus the background-image and background-size, adding a background color and then upping the z-index to 1 and this does the job!

Comment: @bigdaveygeorge You don't need to up the z-index to 1. Keep it -1 and make sure you have 0 set on the container so you don't cover the content (updated my answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `background-blend-mode`

`background-blend-mode` will work with `background-color` without `background-color` it will not work

```css
.container {
  background: url(https://live.staticflickr.com/4561/38054606355_26429c884f_b.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: rgba(238, 238, 238, 0.81);
  background-blend-mode: color;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Some dummy text</p>
</div>
```

Note: This will not work exactly as opacity but it is similar like opacity

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  background: url(https://live.staticflickr.com/4561/38054606355_26429c884f_b.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  background-blend-mode: color;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <p>Some dummy text</p>
</div>
```

> You can do this using Banckground-color: rgba(your color in rbg, opacity) then background-blend-mode: color; This is it